# Apache always fall back to built-in page

Tags: ssl, reverse-proxy, apache2

I made a chess web game in Dart, unsuccessfully trying to deploy to a web host. When I accessed this web app with a public IP, it ran smoothly. However, when accessing with a domain name, it always fall back to default page. Here is my Apache setting:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /home/user/my_web_app

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SSLEngine on

        SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

        SSLVerifyClient none

        #SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>

        ProxyPreserveHost On

        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

I tried both Apache and Nginx; the same condition happened. However, I could not figure out what was wrong? Any suggestion?

[Update on Jun 8, 2017]
I modified the setting in my Apache, finally finding that it was due to Cloud Flare [like this](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/203487280-How-do-I-fix-mixed-content-issues-or-the-infinite-redirect-loop-error-after-enabling-Flexible-SSL-with-WordPress-). I changed my DNS provider. Most issues was solved.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good article for [TroubleShooting Virtual Hosts](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/TroubleshootingVhosts). Here's also a short checklist of things that might help in your situation:

1. Double check this is your only `<VirtualHost *:443>`. Command `apache2ctl -S` may help as it goes through your config, checks syntax and gives a list of all your virtual hosts.
2. You are `ProxyPass`ing everything: remove the unnecessary [`DocumentRoot`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot) directive.
3. Check [`ServerName`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servername). Any vhost that includes the magic `_default_` wildcard is given the same `ServerName` as the main_server, but if the main_ server hasn't one, Apache tries to deduce it based on hostname of the server and using DNS. This may have unexpected results (see [An In-Depth Discussion of Virtual Host Matching](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/details.html)).

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned which OS you are using. I am assuming that if you are using Ubuntu. Then you have to follow certain steps to make you webapp work with domain name.

```
 1. Create a vhost.conf file in /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-vhosfilename.conf
```

I can see you have pasted above the vost configuration file but you are missing one important directive i.e. **ServerName**

2. I am again sharing the configuration of you vhost file pasted above and adding a ServerName directive to it. Just replace your domain name with example.com

   ```
   <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
         ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
         ServerName example.com
         DocumentRoot /home/user/my_web_app

         ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
         CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

         SSLEngine on

         SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
         SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

         SSLVerifyClient none

         #SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
         <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
          SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
         </FilesMatch>

         ProxyPreserveHost On

         ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
         ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    </VirtualHost>
   </IfModule>
   ```
3. After this just save vhost file and enable the vhost configuration file.

   ```
   a2ensite 000-vhosfilename.conf
   ```
4. Now restart the apache and again browse your webapp with domain name. It should work now hopefully.

Comment: The missing `ServerName` isn't ALWAYS a problem, and in this case definitely not an error. As described in my answer, the `_default_` in `<VirtualHost _default_:443>` causes the one from the server configuration to be used, and if not specified even in there, deduced from hostname or reverse DNS. That being said, it might still be the problem here, but for other reasons.

Comment: Ok i was not aware of this. Thanks for educating @Esa.

Comment: But i may be a possibility that the person asking the question has not enabled the website or he may have not pointed DNS correctly.